Find closed orbit problem (Strogatz 8.3.2)
I'm having trouble solving this excercise from Strogatz
Consider the following system for a chemical oscilator:
$$
\dot x= a -x+x^2y
$$
$$
\dot y=b -x^2y
$$
Where $a,b>0$ are parameters and $x,y\geq0$ are concentrations (dimensionless).
Show that all trajectories eventually enter a certain trapping region, to be determined.
Make the trapping region as small as possible. (Hint: Examine the ratio
$\dot y /\dot x$ for large $x$). 
I can kind of see where that region is by using a computer, but is it even possible to find something like that analytically?
